# How can I add an external CD/DVD writer ?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, dvd

I want to add an external CD/DVD writer to my Ubuntu 14.04 system (System 76 Ratel):

the writers in my local electronics store have USB interfaces, and the drives are advertised as windows and mac compatible. So far I have not found a site listing ubuntu compatible external optical read-write drives, and I cannot return the drives after I open them and plug them in.

Has anyone - used an external CD/DVD R/W usb drive with Ubuntu 14.04?  Are there compatibility issues with this kind of hardware?  What makes/models are known to be compatible?

Answer (score 2):

Most and majority of the time if you plug in a DVD+RW or CD+RW on a Ubuntu 14 it will work. It has plug and play capabilities on this particular distribution. You don't need to configure the driver since all the apps that manage the drive work with the drive initialization.

You may not get the app on windows or a mac but on Ubuntu 14 you won't need it; leave it to Ubuntu CD/DVD+RW apps that manage the drive. Ubuntu 14 should already come with a CD/DVD+RW program or you can install more from the Ubuntu Software Center.

If you want you may be able to use WINE on Linux to simulate windows programs that will manage the drive with its software; im not sure how smooth that will work. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a DVD writer in an external 3.5" USB dock.
The writer is automaticaly viewed by Ubuntu.
I can read DVD and burn DVD with a standard burner software. (Brasero, k3b, ...)

You can launch your software in sudo mode to see if its work better